# Why is my Canon 600D showing card write protect switch as set to lock, when it isn't?

Tags: canon-600d, sdcard

Canon 600D **showing card write protect switch is set to lock**, even though the SD card was set to unlock mode/read-write mode. Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried the same card in another device?

Comment: Have you also tried using a different card?

Answer (score 1):

Yup! I can answer this one...

put the card into your computer and manually erase all the data on it. When a canon 60d or 70d can't read data on the card (like it was used in another camera), it will say the card is locked because it doesn't want you to overwrite the data.

Answer (score 0):

Is the phisical lock in the unlocked position and not broken? Try moving the switch multiple times to be sure that it is not oxidised.

Then try the card also on the PC or another camera.

Also verify in Windows that the folder does not have some strange permisisons applied. If oyu can only read it, then download all the files oyu have on it and then format the card with the camera or pc.

**EDIT BASED ON YOUR NEW TITLE**

You say "when switch is set to lock". the switch should NOT be set to lock. when it is in lock mode you cannot write!

Comment: Not Brokened, and that SD working fine in PC and in other camera also,

Comment: did you try a different card in the same camera?

Comment: You say "when switch is set to lock". the switch should NOT be set to lock. when it is in lock mode you cannot write!

Comment: Went to an nearer canon shop,it was SD slot problem and i replaced it with new SD slot, now it was working fine